# Custom Select Projection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a simple class with some properties and I would like to be able to expose a `select` method in order to return another object, (just like linq select method does). For instance:

```
class Person
{
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public string Address {get; set;}
  public string City {get; set;}

  public TItem SelectProjection(..);
}

Person p = new Person();
var other = p.SelectProjection(p => new { p.Name, p.City});
```

Is this possible?

@@EDIT

I've a custom class for business logic, but I expose `IList` only to mantain my code decoupled (no `IQueryable`).
So, if you want to execute some projection you can populate my property string with comma separator:

```
BusinessClass.SelectFields = "Name, Surname, City";
```

But by the way it's easy keying wrong property name, so I prefer lambda:

```
BusinessClass.SelectField = p => new {p.Name, p.Surname, p.City};
```

Comment: So why not call Select?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to accomplish a little more?  Currently it's unclear what you want to accomplish and why you wouldn't just use the select method as @PanagiotisKanavos suggests.

Comment: You aren't decoupling anything if you provide IList instead of IQueryable, quite the opposite. IList is a more specific interface than IQueryable, plus IList implies that the selection has already executed while IQueryable allows you to defer execution

Comment: What??? IList is more specific interface than IQueryable?? :)

Comment: The edit is a totally different question than the original. What are you asking? How is BusinessClass related to Person?

Comment: @bit it is, actually. IList<T> makes specific promises about ordering and implies a materialized list. IQueryable is an abstraction over any IEnumerable, including IList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you mean.

```
public T SelectProjection<T>(Func<T> personFunc) 
{
        return personFunc();
}

 Person p = new Person();
 p.Address = "TestAdress";
 var x = p.SelectProjection<dynamic>(() => new {p.Address});
```

Output:

[image]

Example 2:

```
  Person p = new Person();
  p.Address = "TestAdress";
  p.City = "TestCity";
  var x = p.SelectProjection<dynamic>(() => new {p.Address, p.City});
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. Research delegates, `IEnumerable<T>` and the `yield return` statement. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to accomplish, it's difficult to give a more precise answer.